# Hide the boxes in a histogram with errorbars in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot histogram with errorbars.  How can I hide the boxes so just the errorbars remain?

I can achieve this effect for a single data set using the plain errorbars style and hiding the marker at the center, but I would like to use the histogram style to show multiple series on the same plot.

My code currently looks like this:

```
set style data histograms
set style histogram errorbars lw 2

plot "mydata.dat" using $2:$3:xtic(1) title "Series1", \
               "" using $4:$5         title "Series2"
```

The following lines make the boxes too small to appear at typical zoom levels, but I'd prefer to explicitly disable them.

```
set boxwidth 0.00001
set style fill solid noborder
```

Comment: I don't understand what the plain errorbars style is missing to fulfill your needs. Could you elaborate on `I would like to use the histogram style to show multiple series on the same plot`? Possibly with a sketch or link to an image?

Comment: For example, I could have three series of data, each sharing the same set of independent (x-axis) values.  For each independent value, I'd like the three errors bars for the three series plotted side-by-side, centered over that spot on the x-axis.  The errorbars should be color-coded by series, with the plot legend providing the series--color mapping.  The code in the question produces the desired plot, except for the undesired boxes under the error bars.  If the errorbars style can do this multiple-series plotting sans boxes, please show me how in an answer.  I'll happily upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do:

```
set style data histograms
```

Instead just do:

```
plot "mydata.dat" with errorbars
```

If this does not solve your question, can you point me to an image of a plot similar to what you are trying to achieve?